# loading macro files in a directory, transparently

Tags: freemarker

I am looking for a way to separate the repetitive html codes from web pages, and for this I am planning to use the macro functionality. The problem here is for every macro I need to put this macro in a file, or put some of them in a file and include this in the template file.

What I need is to include once just the directory name something like

```
<#import "/tags/widgetDirectory" as widgets />
```

here the /tags/widgetDirectory is a directory , and every files here can be seen as a macro defined.

when I need to insert a code part from a file from this directory lets say slide.ftl I will just use

```
 <@widgets.slider />
```

the system will check for slider.ftl in the /tags/widgetDirectory directory . here the slider.ftl can have <#macro> as first and  as last line , or these can transparently added and system can load it as a macro

this will easy my designer work.

Maybe there is better way for doing this kind of widgets/components based web design ?

best regards,

Answer (score 0):

This feature (importing directories) is something that's planned for FM actually... but it won't happen anytime soon. But I guess it can be solved fairly well with a hack right now. Instead of `#import`, use your own `TemplateMethodModelEx`, that you could use like `<#assign widgets = importDirectory('/tags/widgetDirectory') >`. This will return a `TemplateHashModel` that's also implemented by you and is bound to the directory path. When an item of that hash is get, it uses `Environment.getCurrentEnvironment().include`. The included file is expected to create a macro with name `__main` or something. So then you get that variable with `Environment.getCurrentNamespace().get("__main")` and return it as the result of the hash lookup. Of course this hash should also maintain a cache, so that if the same item is get twice, it wont include the template for the second time, just return the macro extracted earlier. This can be developer further, so that if the include file didn't define `__main`, then it's supposed that it prints directly to the output, and so it will be included again, when the "tag" is called again.

Comment: I can try to add this feature, any recommendation on how to start ? where to check whether anyone is already involved with this ?

Comment: Nobody works on it. So if you are interested, you can fork the master on Github, and at some point we should discuss the details on the freemarker-devel mailing lists.